# FluentValidation and the GreaterThanOrEqualTo rule with the value 0

Tags: validation, fluentvalidation

I have a problem with fluentvalidation (version 3.4.6.0 with fluentvalidation.MVC4, jQuery validation 1.9.0.1), the validation will fail when the value is 0 and it should not. Here is my code and a failing test.

```
public class SomeModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}

public class EditMachineValidator : AbstractValidator<SomeModel>
{
    public SomeModelValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Price).NotEmpty();
        RuleFor(x => x.Price).GreaterThanOrEqualTo(0m);
    }
}

[Fact]
public void Should_Not_Have_Error_When_Price_Is_Zero()
{
    var validator = SomeModelValidator();
    validator.ShouldNotHaveValidationErrorFor(x => x.Price, 0m);
}
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after some tests,  `GreaterThanOrEqualTo` is not the problem.

It's coming from

```
RuleFor(x => x.Price).NotEmpty();
```

as a `0` value is considered as `empty` !
If you remove it, it will work.

Comment: Also in the documentation... "[NotEmpty Validator](https://fluentvalidation.net/built-in-validators.html#notempty-validator)
Description: Ensures that the specified property is **not** null, an empty string or whitespace (or the **default value** for value types,**eg 0 for int**)"